# Working on an angular without the node_modules folder and I can't run npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

> npm resolution error report
>
> While resolving: front-movit@0.0.0
> Found: @angular/common@14.3.0
> node_modules/@angular/common
> @angular/common@"^14.2.12" from the root project
>
> Could not resolve dependency:
> peer @angular/common@">=13.0.0 <14.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@8.3.0
> node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select
> @ng-select/ng-select@"^8.1.1" from the root project
>
> Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
> to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

**And here's our package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "front-movit",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.12",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^31.0.0",
    "@ds/core": "^0.0.10",
    "@ds/form": "^0.0.4",
    "@ds/grid": "^0.0.6",
    "@ds/plugins": "^0.0.2",
    "@ds/utils": "^0.1.1",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.3",
    "@mingleats/ng-extract-i18n-merge": "^1.0.2-SNAPSHOT",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^8.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "fast-json-patch": "^3.0.0-1",
    "follow-redirects": "^1.15.2",
    "glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.1.2",
    "ngx-currency": "^2.5.1",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^11.3.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^11.1.4",
    "ngx-spinner": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-stars": "^1.5.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-translate": "^0.0.1-security",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.6.8",
    "trim": "^1.0.1",
    "trim-newlines": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.2.12",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.21",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.0.21",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "atgcli": "^1.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "ng-extract-i18n-merge": "^2.4.0",
    "react-is": "^16.13.1",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }
}
```

tried with --legacy-pers-deps and it still doesn't work:

> npm ERR! code E404
>
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@ds%2fcore -
> Not found
>
> '@ds/core@^0.0.10' is not in this registry.

Comment: `@ds/core` indeed isn't in the public registry, maybe you need some org-specific configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two problems do not seem to be related.

On one end you are trying to install a package that is not available publicly (`@ds/core`), and on the other end, you are trying to use a version of `@ng-select/ng-select` which is not compatible with your Angular version.

For the first issue, you should make sure you are trying to install the right package, and if it is a package internal to your organization, see internally how you are supposed to install it.

For the second issue, you should upgrade to a new version of `@ng-select/ng-select`.

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select you can see that for Angular 14, you should use the version `9.x.x` of `@ng-select`.

Run `npm i @ng-select/ng-select@9.1.0` (you should fix the first issue first, or remove your dependency on `@ds/core`).